# Trying to exclude footer height from window scroll jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-scroll

I am trying to work with this infinite [scroll](http://demo.smarttutorials.net/jQuery-infinite-scroll-ajax-php-mysql/). This is the JS [link](http://demo.smarttutorials.net/jQuery-infinite-scroll-ajax-php-mysql/js/script.js)

I need to exclude the footer height which is about 150px in height.

Original jQuery from tutorial:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
```

So I changed the jQuery code like this.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#bottom').offset().top)){
```

One more try with:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() -150 == $(document).height()){
```

so both didn't work, infinite scroll only works when I touch the scroll to the end of the browser, then it works.

Hence, I am looking for where I can exclude the footer height, so that user when they touch the footer with scroll, the infinite scroll should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got it right at your second attempt. Have you tried clearing your browser cache, perhaps test in a different browser? I basically did the same, and it works for me. Using `console.log()` can be very useful when trying to figure out these kinds of things.

Do you have a link to the website? Perhaps something else is causing the issue...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    footerDistance = $('#bottom').offset().top;

    if (scrollDistance >= footerDistance) {
        console.log("Infinite scroll time!");
    }
})
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ehnb8dv/2/

Comment: am still working on my localhost. let me try out with your code and update you, thanks for helping.

Comment: No problem. Like I said, I actually think you got it right in one of your attempts.